# python itertools skipping ahead

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of lists. Using itertools, I am basically doing

for result in product([A,B],[C,D],[E,F,G]):
    # test each result

and the result is the desired product, with each result containing one element from each of the lists.  My code tests each of the results element-by-element, looking for the first (and  best) 'good' one.  There can be a very very large number to test.

Let's say I'm testing the first result 'ACE'.  Let's say when I test the second element 'C' I find that 'ACE' is a bad result.  There is no need to test 'ACF' or 'ACG'.  I would want to skip from the failed ACE directly to trying ADE.  Anyway to do this without just throwing the unwanted results on the floor?

If I was implementing this with nested for loops, I would be trying to manipulate the for loop indexes inside the loop and that would not be very nice ... but I do want to skip testing a lot of results.  Can I skip ahead efficiently in itertools?

Comment: If 'C' is a bad result, would it still be a bad result when you got to 'BCE'? Is an individual element always bad, or just when it's in certain combinations?

Comment: @Rod. That was one of the best retags __ever__.

Comment: individual elements aren't bad, there are only bad combinations of elements

Answer (score 1):

itertools is not the best way to go with the concern you have.

If you just have 3 sets to combine, just loop over and when you fail, break the loops. (If you code is complex, set a variable and break right outside.

```
for i1 in [A, B]:
  for i2 in [C, D]:
      for i3 in [E, F, G]:
         if not test(i1, i2, i3):
           break
```

However, if the number of sets that you have is variable, then use a recursive function (backtrack):

```
 inp_sets = ([A,B],[C,D],[E,F,G])
 max_col = len(inp_sets)
 def generate(col_index, current_set):
     if col_index == max_col:
         if test(current_set):
             return current_set
         else:
             return None
     else:
         found = False
         for item in inp_sets[col_index]:
             res = generate(col_index+1, current_set + [item]):
             if res:
                  return res
             elif (col_index == max_col - 1):
                  # Here we are skipping the rest of the checks for last column
                  # Change the condition if you want to skip for more columns
                  return None

result = generate(0, [])
```

Comment: I think you are right - I am going to use a recursive approach.  itertools will let me consume a bunch of output, but the recursive approach leaves me in control of the generator.